# How can I tell gvfs to use noperm - chmod problem on gvfs smb share

Tags: 18.04, mount, samba, gvfs

Since my update to Ubuntu 18.04 I am struggling with an issue affecting multiple applications writing files to the mounted GVFS SMB share.

The error I get often relates to `permission denied`, or `operation not supported`. But file-roller even does not complain when extracting files and just leaves you with 0-bytes files and partial folders.
Investigating further with `unzip` I believe the reason is because of the unsupported `chmod` call, a simple chmod confirms this:

```
$ pwd
/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=<myserver>,share=data/
$ chmod 777 foo.txt 
chmod: changing permissions of 'foo.txt': Operation not supported
```

Mounting the filesystem manually as root results in the same behavior:

```
$ sudo mount.cifs -o guest,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,user,rw //myserver/data /mnt/
$ cd /mnt
$ chmod 777 foo
chmod: changing permissions of 'foo': Operation not permitted
```

Mounting the same share with the `noperm` parameter results in no errors at all. (file-roller can also extract files without issues) I however did not find a way to tell GVFS to use this parameter?

How can I tune GVFS to use the `noperm` parameter, by default?